# kubernetes traffic with own certificates

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster in a corporate environment, where all HTTPS traffic is *man-in-the-middled* and the certificates are replaced with the company owns. Right now, all the applications running on the cluster get the Company's certificates injected by rebuilding the Docker image or by mounting them from a secret and adding them to the local store. This is painful and makes it harder to just use public helm charts and docker images without modifying them.

For example, I'm running jenkins on the cluster, which tries to install plugins from `https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/`. This would normally fail in my case with a SSL exception, unless I add the certficates to the Jenkins keystore.

I was wondering if there's a way to set this up at the cluster level,
So that there's *some* component that deals with this and the applications can then access the internet normally, without being aware of the whole certificate situation?

My thoughts were:

- A cluster proxy pod, that all the applications then use.
- Some ambassador container on each pod, that the apps connect to

I would imagine I'm not the only one in this situation but couldn't find a generic solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [istio](https://istio.io/latest/). It's a service mesh that uses sidecar proxies to (beside other things) take over responsibility for encrypting traffic between applications.

The proxies use the concept of mutual TLS (mTLS), where all connections inside the mesh are encrypted out-of-the-box. The applications them-self don't have to bother with certificates and can send messages in plain text.

Istio also provides a mechanism to [migrate to mTLS](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/mtls-migration/), so you can include your applications into the mesh one by one, switch to mTLS and disable your own certification overhead.

You can set everything up with your own PKI so you're still using your companies certificates. Also you get a bunch of other features like enhanced observability, canary deployments, on the fly token based authentication/authorization and more.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with the applications accessing the outside internet, not about https communication internal to the cluster. I had checked service meshes but I don't think they solve this issue, do they?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by accessing the outside internet. If your in cluster app queries an app running on a VM you can install istio on that VM and integrate it into the mesh. See https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/virtual-machines/ by that you achieve mTLS between the cluster and the VM. If not please clarify what you mean by accessing the outside internet.

Comment: Ah that's what you mean by "off the internet". Can you provide an example. What would your app use of the internet? Like slack or an aws database? I don't 100 % understand the problem.

Comment: I added more detail to the question: basically, I want to use be able to use a docker image from Docker hub, without modifications. When such an image tries to access an HTTPS URL, it would get it with the company's certificates, which are not public and therefore refuse the connection ( unless I manually add them to the Image by rebuilding it). I want to know if there's some kubernetes mechanism (or add-on)  to deal with this at the cluster level, so all applications inside the cluster don't have to deal with it themselves.

Comment: Hm, the istio egress gateway could solve this, if you deploy istio with your own PKI. It would serve as an exit point of your mesh so (public) services, registered via service entry. Not 100 % sure if it solves your issue and on a custom setup it might be require some effort to set it up correctly. Also probably to much effort to introduce istio just for the egress-gateway.